# java opening urls with proxy taking very much time

Tags: java, performance, url, proxy

Im working with java, specifically reading content from web pages, so the thing is that when I open a url using a proxy setting, it takes a lot of time in some cases (up to 15 or 20 secs) and sometimes the same url opens a lot faster (5 to 10 secs), this happens for some urls.
If I dont use the proxy setting the urls open normally (2 to 5 secs).

Do you know why is this happenind and what can be done?
Here is the part of the code

```
   //set the proxy
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "web-proxy.xxx.xx.com");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "xxxx");

   //open url stream, this line is taking a lot of time with proxy...
   BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url
            .openStream()));
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried HttpClient for comparison? Or maybe the proxy is simply slow? Can you substitute a http proxy for testing?

Comment: Hi Gweebz it seems to be as you said that the proxy is slow, I tried with other 2 public anonymous proxies and with one is kind of slow but with the other it is faster.

Comment: Long timeouts are often due to DNS problems. Maybe the proxy is misconfigured? See what happens if you set that proxy as a proxy for your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is a good conection and transfer rate on the proxies. It all depends on what proxy you use (where it is located at).